# String keeps appearing as a dimen in values causing cradle not to run how do you remove?

Tags: android

A few days ago I created a string (value) call prompt_name but somehow its ended up ad a dimen in the values.xml. I keep trying to removing it but the file is rebuilt each time. How can I delete prompt_name so it doesnt occur any more.

Here is the error from the starting the cradle project sync:

```
Gradle tasks :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, 
string 'prompt_name' has no default translation. 
String types not allowed (at 'prompt name' with value 'Name'). 
String types not allowed (at 'prompt name' with value 'Name'). 
Execution failed for task 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt 
BUILD FAILED
```

Here is the line in values.xml:

```
<dimen name="prompt_name">Name</dimen>
```

Comment: _"String types not allowed (at 'prompt name' with value 'Name')"_ it's clear use integer values in between `<dimen>` tag instead of `Name` like `10dp`. And in Android Studio select `Build -> Make project` to get rid from this issue.

Comment: @Shashanth i am still getting this error:

Comment: `Information: Gradle: Executing tasks: [assemble] 
Information: Module "app" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes 
Information: 23-Apr-17 08:53 AM Compilation completed with 2 errors and I warning in 33s844ms 
Error: Gradle: Execution failed for task 
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt`

Comment: `Warning: Gradle: string 'prompt_name' has no default translation. 
! 63) Gradle: String types not allowed (at 'prompt_name' with value 'Name').`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are editing generated values.xml file, this is useless because it is regenerated with each build. Look at the path of this file it looks something like "build\intermediates\res\mreged\debug\values\values.xml".

Instead you have to find real source file where incorrect line comes from, in your case this is probably dimens.xml and fix the line there.